# Defer to outside a function

Tags: go, defer-keyword

A common pattern I use is:

```
resource.open()
defer resource.close()
```

sometimes checking errors in between, which leads to:

```
err := resource.open()
if err != nil{
     //do error stuff and return
}
defer resource.close()
```

Sometimes I will need multiple open/close resources in a row, leading to a variation of the previous 5 lines to be repeated one after another. This variation may be repeated verbatim several times in my code (where I need all the same resources).

It would be wonderful to wrap all this in a function. However doing so would close the resource as soon as the function call is over. Is there any way around this - either deferring to a "level up" the call stack or some other way?

Comment: You can't call another function to defer things. You can have a function that initializes resources and defer close them, and then call another function you passed in as an argument with those resources.

Comment: `defer` runs when the function it's called in returns, period. Repeating 5 trivial lines is incredibly common in Go.

Comment: @Adrian True. Complaining about that is a different topic :) My issue is when I repeat the same 20 trivial lines, where, say, I need the same four resources in several different places.

Comment: If you find yourself needing to open and close the same set of multiple resources many times throughout your code, that sounds like a severe design/architecture issue.

Comment: @V.K.that was the nature of the question - "How can I do this in golang?"

Comment: @Adrian Perhaps. Specifically, I need a redis connection from a pool and then I need to return it. I also need to set a lock on a redis variable. Those two things both require defers. They both need to happen on many http/websocket calls. How would you solve?

Comment: Hard to say without more info. Possibly a wrapper/middleware style solution (sort of like what Burak Serdar suggested).

Comment: @Adrian ok, but that still means I need to open/close several resources. Is this a severe design issue?

Comment: No, opening/closing resources is normal. Having to open/close the same bunch of resources in many places in your code is a design issue.

Comment: @Adrian perhaps open/close was the wrong terminology. I wanted to indicate the necessity to defer a clean up, which is most easily indicated with open/close. get/return to pool, lock/release are other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is using an "initializer" function with callback:

```
func WithResources(f func(Resource1, Resource2)) {
   r1:=NewResource1()
   defer r1.Close()
   r2:=NewResource2()
   defer r2.Close()
   f(r1,r2)
}

func F() {
  WithResources(func(r1 Resource1, r2 Resource2) {
    // Use r1, r2
  })
}
```

The signature of the function `f` depends on your exact use case.

Another way is to use a struct for a resource set:

```
type Resources struct {
   R1 Resource1
   R2 Resource2
   ...
}

func NewResources() *Resources {
   r:=&Resources{}
   r.R1=NewR1()
   r.R2=NewR2()
   return r
}

func (r *Resources) Close() {
   r.R1.Close()
   r.R2.Close()
}

func f() {
   r:=NewResources()
   defer r.Close()
   ...
}
```

Comment: makes sense, but seems very specific to the callback signature.

Comment: Edited to include another method.

Answer (score -8):

> It would be wonderful to wrap all this in a function.

Most probably a lot of people would hate reading such code. So "wonderful" might be very subjective.

> However doing so would close the resource as soon as the function call is over.

Exactly.

> Is there any way around this [...]?

No.

Comment: so your claim is that there is no issue and I am imagining things?

Comment: @WreckFish I am not claiming anything. I am stating the true fact that you cannot change the way defer works. (Which was your question.)

Comment: See accepted answer.